# How to verify search result for having results with only Nonstop flights

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

My Scenario is writing a script to search flights from Los Angles to Houston George Bush Internationational Air port with filters

1. Oneway Flight
2. Nonstop flight

I got search result as in picture

[image]

Now I want to verify results that it should be only having Nonstop flights or not

How i could do this?

I'm using Testcafe testing framework

[Code that i am writing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwP0m.png)

[Error message i got on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4Sbc.png)

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please don't use code/error images, paste [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) code itself.

Answer (score 2):

Use [assertions](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402837/guides/basic-guides/assert) to check if the tested page’s state matches the expected state.

Comment: @Tabish: SO is not a site for free coding advice. If you need to help with something concrete, you need to share your code and concrete problems you have with that implementation. But people won't work here instead of you.

Comment: i was trying writing a code thats why i ask for help out how i could write a correct code

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following code snippet in your test:

```
test('test name', async t =\> {​​​​​​
const elVal = await Selector('#ELEMENTID').value    
console.log(elVal)
}​​​​​​);
```

I suppose you need to use the [Selector Object](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402666/reference/test-api/selector) in your test, since the [ClientFunction Object](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402671/reference/test-api/clientfunction) is intended for retrieving serialized data, so you cannot use the result of ClientFunction for working directly with DOM objects.